# Rename Move command in several dynamic folders

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a `.bat` file that can rename and move a file or files in one bat file that will run every minute. The file it moves will be used in a web site.

There are a few obstacles that make this a problem for me.

The folder structure is like this:
`D:/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Project_Name_Folder4/System_NR_Folder5/Device_Folder6/Date_Folder7/Channel Folder8A` and `8B` and `8C/Time_Folder` (One for each hour) and finally there is the files that is named after the time they was created.jpg

I think I have everything worked out until I get to the Time Folder, because here there will be 24 Folders within 1 day. But I will run the rename/move every minute, so then old folders will be empty.

So is there a command that would take the latest file from any folder under the Channel Folder or is there a command that crawl any folder and then rename/move file.

So how to make it pick up that there are 24 folders and that the files I want is moving throughout these folders within 24 hours from folder `00` then `01` then `02` to `23`.
I will put the bat file in folder 4 so it will work for the rest of the folder structure.

```
@echo off
set year=%date:~6,4% set month=%date:~3,2% set day=%date:~0,2% set
path = D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Projectname4\System NR
Folder5\Device Folder6\%year%-%month%-%day%\Channel Folder8\Time
Folders??\filename*.jpg
MOVE D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Projectname4\System NR Folder5\Device Folder6\%year%-%month%-%day%\ Channel Folder8\Time
Folders??\filename*.jpg D:\Folder1\WEBFOLDER\Project_Folder\Name
Folder\0101\0101.jpg
```

[image: Folder Structure]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It is not difficult at all using `dir` to search and sort. The below example searches for `*.txt` from the root where batch file is executed and sorts them and echo the latest created `.txt` file, as an example:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /S /B /A-D-H /T:C /O:D *.txt') do set "latest=%%a"
echo Latest File: %latest%
```

for more on the switches used in the `dir` command, refer to the documentation when running `dir /?` from `cmd.exe`

Also, as a side note, as part of your script you can use

```
timeout /t 60 >nul
goto restart
```

and have the label `:restart` at the beginning of you script, this will silently wait for 60 seconds and start the process again, so you can run the script continuasly.